# If $A = \text{blkdiag}(G_1DG_1^T, G_2DG_2^T)$ is a block diagonal matrix and $B = C^TC$ is symmetric, how to manipulate $\text{tr}(AB)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, block-matrices

$
\newcommand{\blkdiag}{\operatorname{blkdiag}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}
$Suppose $G_1$ is a $m_1 \times n$ matrix, and $G_2$ is a $m_2 \times n$ matrix. $D$ is a $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with $\{d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n\}$ along the diagonal such that $d_1 \neq d_2 \neq \ldots \neq d_n$. And $C$ is a $n \times m$ matrix.

Let $m = m_1 + m_2$. Then $$A = \blkdiag(G_1DG_1^T, G_2DG_2^T)$$ is a $m \times m$ matrix, and

$$B = C^TC$$ is a $m \times m$ matrix.

I'm interested in manipulating the expression for $\tr(AB)$ such that I can pull out $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i$ outside of the trace operator somehow.

I know this can be done for the following: suppose $A^* = G_1DG_1^T$ is a $m_1 \times m_1$ matrix, and $B^* = C^{*T}C^*$ is a $m_1 \times m_1$ matrix where $C^*$ is $n \times m_1$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\tr(A^*B^*) &= \tr(G_1DG_1^TC^{*T}C^*)\\
&= \tr(DG_1^TC^{*T}C^*G_1)\\
& \sum_{i=1}^n d_i \tr(e_i^TG_1^TC^{*T}C^*G_1e_i)
\end{align*}
where $e_i$ is $i$th unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Can something similar be done for $\tr(AB)$ where $A$ is now a block diagonal matrix? I know that $\tr(A) = \tr(G_1DG_1^T) +\ tr(G_2DG_2^T)$, but I'm not sure how to work with $\tr(AB)$ so that I might be able to pull $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i$ outside of the trace operator.

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more about $C$ and how big $m$ is relative to $n$. Obviously if $C=0$ then one cannot get $\sum_id_i$ from $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that “$\operatorname{blkdiag}(\dots)$” denotes a block diagonal matrix with the respective block cells. Put $G=\operatorname{blkdiag}(G_1, G_2)$,  and $D’=\operatorname{blkdiag} (D,D)$. Then $A = GD’G^T$ so $$\operatorname{tr}(AB)= \operatorname{tr}(GD’G^TB)= \operatorname{tr}(D’G^TBG).$$